# Update , Select and Join using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, select, update

There are 3 tables:

1. `Label (Label_ID,Label_Name)`, Label_ID is Primary Key.
2. `Tracks (Prefix, Label_ID)`, Prefix is Primary Key,Label_ID is empty column
3. `Top100 (Prefix,Label)` No keys in this table.

My query should be such that , For each `prefix` row in **Tracks** table, find an equivalent `prefix` in **top100** table then select `Label` from **top100** table, Match thus selected `Label` with `Label_name` in **Label** table, get its `Label_ID` and Update its value in **Tracks** table.

Can anyone please help me with this query?? Any help much appreciated

Comment: Do you want (for every `Tracks.prefix`) a new row to be inserted or the existing row to be updated?

Comment: yes, every row to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't want (for every `Tracks.prefix`) a new row to be inserted but the existing row to be updated (otherwise you would get collisions on the primary key of `Tracks`). You can this query to check first what will be changed:

```
SELECT 
    tr.prefix,
    tr.label_id AS existing_label_id,
    top.label,
    lbl.label_id AS new_label_id 
FROM 
    Tracks AS tr
  JOIN
    Top100 AS top  ON top.prefix = tr.prefix
  JOIN
    Label AS lbl  ON lbl.label_name = top.label ;
```

and then update:

```
UPDATE
    Tracks AS tr
  JOIN
    Top100 AS top  ON top.prefix = tr.prefix
  JOIN
    Label AS lbl  ON lbl.label_name = top.label
SET
    tr.label_id = lbl.label_id ;
```

Comment: Select query you have provided gives me a cross product, there are 7770 rows each in tracks and top 100 tables